# Laravel Livewire: unexpeced behaviour, view dose not recieve updated data

Tags: laravel, laravel-livewire

hope you're having a good day.

so i have a livewire components that consists of `jobs` and a `viewedJob` attribute, `jobs` is an array of all the jobs that are related to `viewedJob` in some way.

**My Goal**

is to highlight the current `job` in the list that is `viewedJob`.

so in my front-end code i have this logic

```html
    <aside
        class="text-gray-700 text-md  w-auto sm:w-auto md:w-3/12 lg:w-2/12 xl:w-2/12  rounded-md mx-4">
        <ul>
            @foreach($jobs as $job)
                <li :key="$loop->index" 
                   class="@if($viewedJob->id == $job['id']) border border-primary @endif my-1 w-full bg-white p-3 rounded-md @if(!$loop->first) my-3 @endif">
                    <main class="flex w-full items-center justify-between">
                        <div class="flex items-center justify-between">
                            <button wire:click="viewJob({{$job['id']}})" class="truncate focus:outline-none">
                                {{$job['title']}}
                            </button>
                        </div>
                    </main>

            @endforeach
        </ul>
    </aside>
```

notice this

```php
@if($viewedJob->id == $job['id']) 
border border-primary
@endif
```

this should highlight the div that is currently `viewedJob` is equal to.

and this is how i update my property

```php
<button wire:click="viewJob({{$job['id']}})" class="truncate focus:outline-none">
         {{$job['title']}}
</button>
```

and my livewire component looks like this

```php
class JobsIndex extends Component
{
    public $viewedJob;
    public $jobs;

    public function mount() {
        $this->jobs = collect($this->jobs)->map(function ($job) {
            return [
                'ownerName' => $job->owner->name,
                'title' => $job->title,
                'id' => $job->id,
                'location' => $job->location
            ];
        });
    }

    public function viewJob($jobId) {
        $this->viewedJob = Job::find($jobId);
    }

    public function render()
    {
        return view('livewire.jobs-index');
    }
}
```

this is how i update the `viewedJob` property

```php
    public function viewJob($jobId) {
        $this->viewedJob = Job::find($jobId);
    }
```

this is the current behaviour of the application.

[image]

any help would be appreciated, thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to keep your class conditions as simple as possible.

class="`{{ ($viewedJob->id == $job['id']) ? 'border border-primary'' : '' }}` my-1 w-full bg-white p-3 rounded-md `{{ (!$loop->first) ? 'my-3' : '' }}`"